# sidekiq - fall back to standard sync ruby code when redis server is not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I'm using [sidekiq](http://mperham.github.io/sidekiq/) in a rails app to send some emails asynchronously. How can I ensure that the code (the job itself) is executed even when the Redis server is not running.

```
CommentsWorker.perform_async(@user.id, @comment.id)
```

In the comments worker, I'm fetching the user and the comment, and I send an email:

```
def perform(user_id, comment_id)
  user = User.find(user_id)
  comment = Comment.find(comment_id)

  CommentMailer.new_comment(user, comment).deliver
end
```

If I stop the Redis server, my app raises an exception `Redis::CannotConnectError`

I still want to send that email, even when the server is stopped, using old fashioned sync code. I tried to `rescue` from that exception, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. The solution was to test for a redis connection and rescue from the exception, but *before* the call to `perform_async`. There's now only the minor issue of having to wait for the connection to time out, but I guess I can live with that.

```
redis_available = true
Sidekiq.redis do |connection|
  begin
    connection.info
  rescue Redis::CannotConnectError
    redis_available = false
  end
end


if redis_available
  CommentsWorker.perform_async(user.id, @comment.id, @award.id)
else
   #sync code
   user = User.find(user_id)
   comment = Comment.find(comment_id)

   CommentMailer.new_comment(user, comment).deliver
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this has already been answered and I liked @mihai's approach, but we wanted to reuse the code elsewhere in our application for multiple workers. Also, we wanted to make it more generic to work with any worker.

We decided to extend `Sidekiq::Worker` with an additional method `perform_async_with_failover` defined below:

```
module Sidekiq
  module Worker
    module ClassMethods
      def perform_async_with_failover(*args)
        redis_available = true
        Sidekiq.redis do |connection|
          begin
            connection.info
          rescue Redis::CannotConnectError
            redis_available = false
          end
        end
        if redis_available
          # process the job asynchronously
          perform_async(*args)
        else
          # otherwise, instantiate and perform synchronously
          self.new.perform(*args)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Improving Kyle's solution above since I guess using `connection.info` is to see if there is a connection available. But my understanding is that `info` would send extra commands when redis is online and that is unnecessary. I would just catch the exception from `perform_async` instead:

```
module Sidekiq
  module Worker
    module ClassMethods
      def perform_async_with_failover(*args)
        begin
          # process the job asynchronously
          perform_async(*args)
        rescue Redis::CannotConnectError => e
          # otherwise, instantiate and perform synchronously
          self.new.perform(*args)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**edited**:
you may want to have a look at [sidekiq error handling section](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling)

Comment: @mihai, sorry, haven't read your question to the very end. So the exception still raises or the email is simply not sent?

Comment: the exception is still being raised...i'm not sure why I can't `rescue` from it, probably something related to multi-threading, perhaps?

Comment: @mihai, the exception is raised in `perform` method?

Comment: @mihai, you may also want to use `exception_notification` gem that sidekiq can integrate with. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling

Answer (score 1):

Implementing @mihai's answer I ended up creating a service to encapsulate the action of "gracefully delivering email".

Example of calling the class:

```
message = MyMailer.order_confirmation(email_arguments)
GracefullyDeliverEmail.call(message)
```

The class:

```
class GracefullyDeliverEmail
  ###
  # Attempts to queue email for async sending but fails
  # gracefully to delivering it immediately.
  #
  # @param context.message {ActionMailer::MessageDelivery}
  ###
  def self.call(message)
    validate!(message)

    if redis_available?
      message.deliver_later(wait: 2.mins)
    else
      message.deliver_now # Fallback to inline delivery
    end
  end

  # == Private Methods ======================================================
  private

  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993080/sidekiq-fall-back-to-standard-sync-ruby-code-when-redis-server-is-not-running/42247913#42247913
  def redis_available?
    redis_available = true
    Sidekiq.redis do |connection|
      begin
        connection.info
      rescue Redis::CannotConnectError
        redis_available = false
      end
    end
    redis_available
  end

  def validate!(message)
    if !message.is_a?(ActionMailer::MessageDelivery)
      raise "message must be of class ActionMailer::MessageDelivery"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there are active redis clients, something like:

```
def perform(user_id, comment_id)
  user = User.find(user_id)
  comment = Comment.find(comment_id)

  redis_info = Sidekiq.redis { |conn| conn.info }

  CommentMailer.new_comment(user, comment).deliver

  rescue Redis::CannotConnectError
    CommentMailer.new_comment(user, comment)
end
```

should do it.

Comment: this doesn't work either...`conn.info` also raises the exception. however the solution is to do a `rescue` inside that block...which seems to work

Comment: So you don't even need the `if` clause, right? Check my edit.